# React, several useEffect with same dependencies, is't bad?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some question while working with React.js. Say we have those `useEffect`s that have the same dependencies inside some `a.jsx`:

```
// a.jsx
const Main = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(1);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(2);
  }, []);

  return <p>asdf</p>
}
```

In a `b.jsx`, I've gathered functions to have one `useEffect`, like below:

```
//b.jsx
const Main = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(1);
    console.log(2);
  }, []);

  return <p>asdf</p>
}
```

What is the different? Which one is the best practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best practice(s) are the ones that:

- Make your code easy to read.
- Easy to maintain.
- Follow common best practices like **DRY** (Don't Repeat Yourself).

That last one I think is applicable here. An `useEffect` with an empty dependency array is *roughly* equivalent to the `componentDidMount` lifecycle. A component can only be mounted once per mounting, so you can reduce (*not repeat*) code by placing all mounting logic into a single mounting `useEffect` hook.

```
// b
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(1);
  console.log(2);
}, []);
```

If some logic has the same dependencies later during rerenders, then logically it still makes sense to place them into a single effect hook.

```
// b
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(1);
  console.log(2);
}, [depA, depB]);
```

Even if they have the same dependencies but you want to conditionally call some functions internally, still it makes sense to place them into a single effect hook.

```
// b
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(1);
  if (depB) {
    console.log(2);
  }
}, [depA, depB]);
```

It's when the dependencies are different that you'll want to use separate effects.

```
// a
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(1);
}, [depA]);

// b.jsx
useEffect(() => {
  if (depC) {
    console.log(1);
  }
  console.log(2);
}, [depB, depC]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Having many `useEffect` is not a problem, but for maintainability, if it is possible, having one is the best choice. However, in some cases it isn't; for example, if you have different logic to execute or different dependencies like so:

```js
const Main = () => {
  // this one runs once when the component mounts
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(1);
  }, []);
  
  // this one runs on mount and also every time someVarible changes 
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(2);
  }, [someVariable]);

  return <p>asdf</p>
}
```

Comment: Does it mean Having one useEffect is 'little little bit' more faster than having many?

Comment: No it makes your code more clean.